# OpenBSD 5.9 fetching the source code via CVS after fresh installation of OpenBSD 5.9 # anoncvssh: cant' load library 'libc.so.84.2'

Tags: openbsd

I use OpenBSD for 4 years on this hardware, without any problems.

Since I'm using this computer as a build system, each release will be reinstalled.

Then, OpenBSD will be raised to stable, with cvs.

Then, a new release of OpenBSD is made and burned to CD.

I'm using OpenBSD since the year 2000.

This is my favourite hobby.

So far so good. I have reinstalled my OpenBSD 5.9.

And wanted to get the source with cvs.

This time it did not work.

You need to install the source by hand.

Until the patch 003: RELIABILITY FIX: March 16, 2016   All architectures

Then you can install the rest with cvs.

I would like to install the source code on OpenBSD 5.9 via cvs

CVSROOT=anoncvs@anoncvs.spacehopper.org:/cvs

cd /usr

cvs -d $CVSROOT get -rOPENBSD_5_9 -P src

The result of this command: anoncvssh: cant't load library 'libc.so.84.2'

dmesg = OpenBSD 5.9 (GENERIC.MP) #1888: Fri Feb 26 01:20:19 MST 2016

Comment: Works for me. Maybe your system is broken somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must get the source code and install it.

```
http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/5.9/src.tar.gz
http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/5.9/sys.tar.gz
http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/5.9/xenocara.tar.gz
http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/5.9/ports.tar.gz
```

Copy everything in the /home directory.

Now unpack the source code.

```
tar -xvpzf src.tar.gz -C /usr/src
tar -xvpzf sys.tar.gz -C /usr/src
tar -xvpzf xenocara.tar.gz -C /usr
tar -xvpzf ports.tar.gz -C /usr
```

http://www.openbsd.org/errata59.html

Copy all of the patches from the OpenBSD 5.9 release in the /home directory.

```
http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/patches/5.9.tar.gz
tar -xvzf 5.9.tar.gz -C /home
```

Then `cd /home/5.9/common/`

Then `less /home/5.9/common/001*`

Then `signify -Vep /etc/signify/openbsd-59-base.pub -x 001_sshd.patch.sig -m - | (cd /usr/src && patch -p0)`

And then rebuild and install sshd:

```
cd /usr/src/usr.bin/ssh
make obj
make depend
make
make install
```

Follow the instructions in the patches.
Do this with all patches.

Then you can update the source code with cvs to stable without this stupid error.

```
CVSROOT=anoncvs@anoncvs.spacehopper.org:/cvs
cd /usr/src
cvs -d $CVSROOT up -rOPENBSD_5_9 -Pd
```